# Prove/Provide counter example about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Prove/Provide counter example:

1. Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation. $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ is linear dependent set. Then $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_k)\}$ is linear dependent.
2. Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation. $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_k)\}$ is linear dependent set. Then $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ is linear dependent.

The first one is a proof: we have scalars, not all are zeros, which $c_1v_1+...+c_kv_k=0$,

Then $T(c_1v_1+...+c_kv_k)=0 \to c_1T(v_1)+...+c_kT(v_k)=0$ so {$T(v_1),...,T(v_k)$} is linear dependent.

In the second one, I think that if we take the zero transformation that might be a counter example:

By choosing $T_0:V \to W$ , $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_k)\}$ is linear dependent set (all are zeros), but $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ can be linearly independent if this is a basis for $V$ for example.

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. Both solutions are fine.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos The proof is almost correct. If $(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ are linearly independent, there is a linear combination $\sum_k c_k v_k=0$ with at least one $c_k\neq 0$. But then $\sum_k c_k T(v_k)=0$ wth the same $c_k\neq 0$. Hence, they are linearly dependent.

Comment: Cool, thank you!!